# Cannot alert value from onkeydown event

Tags: javascript

Nothing I have found or tried so far has helped or produced anything that worked properly.

Here is an example of one my my dozens of failed attempts:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Keyboard Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
onkeydown=text
function test() {
var key=String.fromCharCode;
if (key=="a")
alert("Hello!");
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Could someone please show me how to attempt this properly and why it works?

Comment: `onkeydown=text; function test()` There's one problem. You're missing a closing brace on your function, and you should be taking the event as an argument to `test` to get the character code from it. You should copy-and-paste an existing example, get it to work, and then deconstruct it.

Comment: I tried to give your question a decent title.  Remember this *isn't* a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: Not sure what environment you are working in, but getting things like Firebug, or looking at jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/aq2Up/) can help you learn JS as well as build mini examples to ask questions about.

Answer (score 0):

"onkeydown=text" -- is this a typo? Do you mean "onkeydown=test"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that does mostly what you're trying to do, but in a very different way: http://jsbin.com/usonoh/1/edit

HTML:

```
<input id="foo">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
  if (ev.which === 'A'.charCodeAt(0)) {
    alert("A!");
  }
});
```

Hopefully it's pretty straightforward, but what it's doing is getting the HTML element with ID "foo", adding an event listener (which is just a function that you pass in) to the "keydown" event, and then in the listener itself we check whether the key that was just pressed in the "foo" input is a charcode 65 (the "a" key).

In general, you should attach event listeners in Javascript, and you should use the addEventListener method rather than setting the on* properties.

I highly recommend Mozilla Developer Network for finding DOM API information; here are the relevant pages for this example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Try like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dx6eJ/1/)

```
document.onkeydown = function test(ev) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode);
    if (key === "A") {
        alert("Hello!");
    }
}
```